# HIbernate 5, Oracle and Native query - breaking behaviour when upgrading from H4?

Tags: oracle, hibernate

We're doing an hibernate upgrade (from 4.3 to latest 5.5) on our main application, and we found a breaking change which we couldn't well figure out.

We've a fairly beefy query that was written back in the day and it's quite important for us (contains a few calculations on our transactions like the following:

```
SUM(DECODE(SIGN(at.bal_value_date - :valueDate), -1, at.amount, 0)) AS Day_M1
```

We were passing the `valueDate` as: `query.setParameter("valueDate", valueDate, TemporalType.DATE);` (the `valueDate` variable is a plain `java.util.Date`). The column is a java `DATE` (which can contains date and time with second precision, no milliseconds or timzone).

When upgrading to Hibernate 5, we started getting this error: `SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND`.
Activating debug log, we found that Hibernate 4 was binding the value as a DATE, while v5 is mapping as a TIMESTAMP. This change seems to be the cause that is making Oracle calculate the result differently thus erroring out.

We did manage to solve by changing the parameter to a string and the query to this:

```
SUM(DECODE(SIGN(at.bal_value_date - TO_DATE(:valueDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')), -1, at.amount, 0)) AS Day_M1
```

(we couldn't use java `LocalDate` as this doesn't have a time component which we need).

Any idea why this change in behaviour? Possible bug or expected behaviour?

Environment Java is 8.xxx (can't remember off the top of my head), spring 5.2.4, Oracle is 19c.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug for which you should create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Thanks, will provide one in the next days.